# What's a regular expression for a certain ruleset in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Specifically, it should be 6 or more alphanumerics (0-9 + a-z).

The second character is a letter.

The third character is an odd number.

Any help?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example regex that matches this for ASCII is

```
^[0-9A-Za-z][A-Za-z][13579][0-9A-Za-z]{3,}$
```

PHP code

```
<?php
$test = '0A1000';
if (preg_match('/^[0-9A-Za-z][A-Za-z][13579][0-9A-Za-z]{3,}$/', $test)) {
    // Do some stuff
    echo "matched";
}
```

Comment: How would I use this in preg_match?

Comment: Updated regex and added an example in PHP.